# Convergence of $\frac{e^{\arctan(n)}}{1+n^2}$ by comparison test.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Checking whether the following series converges.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\arctan(n)}}{1+n^2}$$ .

Since $\frac{e^{1.6}}{1+n^2} > \frac{e^{arctan(n)}}{1+ n^2}$ and it also converges by limit 
comparison test with 1/n^2. Therefore the sum converges.

Is there any problem with this reasoning since we can also use integral test to prove convergence here. Albeit this looks less neat.

Comment: Try putting dollar signs around math text to make it more readable.

Comment: The approach is valid but I do not understand the meaning of $91$. Of course, this is an upper bound for $\arctan(n)$ , but why not replace it by , lets say , $1.6$ ?

Comment: Additionally : Is the denominator $1+n^2$ ? I guess so because otherwise the "/1" is unneccessary.

Comment: @Peter Can we still say e^1.6/1+n^2 > e^arctan(n)/1+ n^2 ?

Comment: Yes because the arctan is calculated in radians and bounded by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @Peter , l forgot to convert 91 into radian. Thanks .

Comment: Please check whether I changed the intent of the question with my edits !

Comment: @peter.  Thanks for editing.I suck at writing the little codes. Yes that's what l intended.